# What are the limitations on my divine focus choices?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spellcasting-focus

What are the limitations of what can be selected for a divine focus?

How big can my holy symbol be?

Can clerics use a shield or weapon as their divine focus? Can I set the divine focus into a ring, or store it in the hollow pommel of a weapon, or wear it as an amulet?

If I pick a metal divine focus, can I have that welded or soldered onto a steel shield or weapon?

Comment: At least some of these need to be split off into other questions; if you focus on the key question of what pieces of gear a divine focus can be, or be part of, this will be much more focused. Spitting out a dozen questions in rapid fire is not really the thing.

Comment: I've cut out: your question about Rogar, and your questions about bucklers, and just focused this on what the limitations are around divine focus choices. You should ask those other questions separately. You can still access them by going to your revision history, by clicking the [edited X time ago](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/80515/revisions) link in the bottom center.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Most divine foci are holy symbols...

[Components](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Components) on Divine Focus says

> A divine focus component is an item of spiritual significance. The divine focus for a cleric or a paladin is a holy symbol appropriate to the character's faith. The divine focus for a druid or a ranger is a sprig of holly, or some other sacred plant.

A cleric or paladin or similar's [holy symbol](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/toys-games-puzzles) can be made from any one of variety of materials, while a druid or ranger or similar tends toward [holly and mistletoe](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/equipment.html#spellcasting-and-services).

Holly and mistletoe cost *and* weigh a negligible amount. The game hasn't focused on those pretty much *at all* (except in very rare cases such as this [magic ring](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-sacred-mistletoe)) and, instead, provides all kinds of information about holy symbols. If you're *really* wondering about holly and mistletoe and not holy symbols, talk to the GM. Holy symbols get all the love.

#### ...And a holy symbol *is* versatile...

All holy symbols weigh 1 lb. except those made of wood, which have negligible weight. However, I assume a cleric or paladin's holy symbol *could* be—I mean, if he really *wanted* it to be—as large as the character could drag: scaling *many* nonstandard things up or down will depend on the GM's house rules for doing so (that is, so far as I'm aware, no rules are provided for, for example, inappropriately sized holy symbols), but I tend to use the [Armor for Unusual Creatures chart](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/armor#TOC-Armor-for-Unusual-Creatures) for resizing pretty much everything because it's simple and convenient.

It's probably safe to assume the typical holy symbol is, by default, equivalent to a light weapon for a creature of its size, so a one-size-category increase makes it one-handed, and a two-size-category increase makes it two-handed. For example, if he wants to [channel energy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric#TOC-Channel-Energy-Su-) with it or ward off a [vampire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire) with it or whatever, a Medium creature must use two hands to present a Huge holy symbol. However, I warn you: I *must* speculate here because I've *never* seen an inappropriately sized holy symbol be an issue despite there always being at least one divine spell caster in every party I've been in over the past several years, and sometimes *I* am the one *playing* that divine spell caster.

#### ...But a holy symbol's *not* usually armor, a shield, or a weapon...

By default, armor, a shield, or a weapon isn't and can't be a divine focus. However, paying someone with the feat [Craft Reliquary Arms and Shields](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/create-reliquary-arms-and-shields) 250 gp can turn any armor, shield, or weapon into a holy symbol divine focus (but, apparently, *not* a holly-and-mistletoe divine focus).

#### ...And a divine caster must be able to [manipulate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Choosing-a-Spell) the holy symbol and may want to be able to [*present*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric#TOC-Channel-Energy-Su-) the holy symbol, too...

[Choosing a Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Choosing-a-Spell) says that

> To cast a spell, you must be able to... and manipulate the material components or focus (if any).

This means a cleric can wear a holy symbol around the neck or as a ring or whatever as long as the cleric can manipulate the holy symbol while casting a spell (holy symbol manipulation, by the way, is done with the same one free hand that's *also* satisfying the spell's somatic components *and* preparing and manipulating material components—yes, that's a busy hand!).

However, actually *presenting* a holy symbol—for example, to channel energy or to ward off vampires—, I've always seen ruled as needing an empty hand (although not necessarily an empty hand *capable of wielding a weapon*—a holy symbol held in a hand that's also toting a light shield, for instance, is fine). (This makes the necklace—which the cleric can argue can be strongly presented using *either* hand—a more versatile choice than the ring which a cruel GM may rule is occasionally *on the wrong hand*.)

A holy symbol stored in a weapon's [hollow pommel](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-and-armor-accessories#TOC-Pommel-hollow) (a real thing with statistics in *Pathfinder*) can't be used until extracted, but if a foe thinks a cleric powerless after snatching the cleric's holy symbol, the foe could be in for a surprise next round. (It likely takes a move action that provokes attacks of opportunity to [retrieve a stored item](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#Table-Actions-in-Combat) from a hollow pommel, but ask the GM.)

#### ...and you probably *can't* just nail a cross to a shield (or whatever) then use the shield as a holy symbol

The existence of the feat Craft Reliquary Arms and Shields leads me to believe that trying to attach a holy symbol to armor, a shield, or a weapon probably just destroys the holy symbol, but you can run it by the GM and see if you can save 250 gp.

---

Options are identical for *unholy* symbols if you're evil.

Comment: You may want to add [Reliquary Arms and Shields](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/create-reliquary-arms-and-shields/) to this otherwise great answer?

Comment: @Ifusaso Admittedly, I called it *Craft* instead of *Create*, but it's already mentioned twice. Is there something about it I've forgotten?

Comment: Sorry I read over it, I was on my mobile at the time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a group of items called [channel foci](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/toys-games-puzzles#table-channel-foci). They have special powers when charged with channel energy.

> A channel focus is a garment or other object that incorporates a holy or unholy symbol, and has a special power when a member of that symbol’s religion channels energy through it.
>
> [...]
>
> **The cleric can use the focus as a holy symbol** (whether activated or not)...

Among those are: Consecrated weapon, Sanctified shield.

So there are ways to have a weapon and/or shield that has a holy/unholy symbol on it and can be used as such.

Comment: This answer does not actually answer the question asked, which was asking about limitations for a Divine Focus. The channeling foci that you have linked to are all items with special properties that they produce when they are channeled into but they are not the same thing as a Divine Focus.

Comment: While it does not answer the header it DOES answer the question asked in the post: "Can clerics use a shield or weapon as their divine focus?" because, as I linked all channeling foci incorporates a holy symbol.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the text, but this line: "This triggers the item’s ability; the channel does not have any of its normal effects" leads me to believe that these are NOT in fact normal foci. I could be misinterpreting the RAW.

Comment: They each have a special ability, that is their main use. But the description states that a channel focus is an object that incorporates a holy or unholy symbol. And because of that clerics can use them as divine focus.

Comment: Quoted another line, that makes it explicit that they count as holy symbols