# Can clerics use a focus instead of divine focus when casting a spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, cleric, divine, spellcasting-focus

I am a cleric who recently had their holy symbol stolen from them (my backup was in my backpack). I needed to cast a spell. From my list of prepared spells I had summon monster, which has both a focus and DF. As a divine spellcaster am I allowed to cast the spell using its focus instead of the divine focus?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### To cast a [divine spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Divine-Spells) that possesses a divine focus (DF) [component](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Components), a typical caster must employ a divine focus even if the same spell also possesses an arcane focus component

On Magic on [Components](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Components) on Divine Focus says

> If the Components line [of a spell] includes F/DF or M/DF, the arcane version of the spell has a focus component or a material component (the abbreviation before the slash) and the divine version has a divine focus component (the abbreviation after the slash).

In other words, a typical divine caster *cannot* opt to use the arcane focus instead of a divine focus. For example, a typical level 1 cleric must have a [holy symbol](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80515/8610) to cast a [*summon monster*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster) spell, while a typical level 1 wizard must have a tiny bag and a small candle.

***Note:*** A spell's Components entry can be confusing because sometimes a spell (like the summon monster *spells)* seems *to require a divine focus other than a the cleric's typical divine focus, when, in actuality, the spell doesn't. For example, a* summon monster *spell's components of* V, S, F/DF (a tiny bag and a small candle) *include only the necessary arcane focus, boldly assuming the reader knows that the divine caster will need, instead, his divine focus. However, some spells mandate* only *a focus (e.g. the* [destruction](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/destruction) *spell), and* both *arcane* and *divine casters must employ such a focus! This isn't helped by a spell like* [scrying](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scrying) *that's just all sorts of [confusing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/87438/8610). In fact, I find a spell's whole Components entry an alienating jargon issue that I hope is one day cleaned up for ease of use.*

Comment: And what does a level 1 wizard/level 1 cleric multi-class need?

Comment: @daleM what do you mean there? as both spell lists are separate from each other......summon from wizard needs different things than the summon form cleric

Comment: @DaleM: That depends on which class you're using to cast a particular spell. Divine spells require devine components, arcane spells require the arcane components, as mentioned in the entry of each spell.  Note: losing your Devine Focus is about the worst that can happen to a Cleric, don't be surprised if some atonement is in order.

Comment: @DaleM A divine focus to cast his cleric *summon monsters* but, instead, a tiny bag and small candle to cast his wizard *summon monsters* . I thought title, though long, was clear. Should I clarify that?

Comment: @agodwithoutananswer While the holy symbol has "spiritual significance," I've not heard that losing one requiring a creature to atone for its loss. It's 1 gp; just buy a new one. In fact, why by level 2 a cleric *didn't* have a dozen secreted about his person (like the Joker does knives) seems, to me, a bit strange! This probably comes down to playstyle, though, so it's cool.

Comment: Why does the cleric kit come with a spell components pouch then?

Comment: @Fering Because clerics are still sometimes burdened with spells requiring *only* a M or F component rather than a M/DF component or the like,  especially if a cleric picks a domain that includes spells that are traditionally arcane. Such spells assume they'll be cast by a beardy old dude with a staff and a satchel full of poop and spiders rather than a plate-armored crusader-evangelist of an arcane-spell-granting god, so a lot of spells mandate a satchel of poop of spiders rather than the divine focus. A cleric kit includes a spell component pouch so the cleric can cast nearly all his spells.

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan: I was referring to the thief! No but seriously, atonement is an actual term, as much as a spell. I do agree my post is not based on RAW, but rather on life-long experience with devious DM's (that, for example, steal Divine Focuses from Clerics).